# Jenkins pipeline running on a shared machine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a unique circumstance for my Jenkins pipeline.
For reasons that are beyond my control, our Jenkins node exist on machines developers use. That is they can run concurrently while a developer is using the machine as well.

While this is ok for the most part, we run into issues when we reach the testing stage within our pipeline. This is because our applications / simulator utilize shared memory resources.
To try to fix this, we've disabled concurrent builds via Jenkins so that it doesn't impede itself. This does not check however if there is a user locally running on a machine. I can check if a file exists and use that to determine if anyone is running locally, but I haven't found a way to do this before a job executes.

The issues we've run into is that a build begins via Jenkins, then 'fails' when it reaches the testing state because there is a local developer already using the shared memory. Ideally, we'd like to check to see if this local resource is available before beginning a job, and if it is not, try the next available node to do so.

I have read through the lockable resource plugin, but it appears that only prevents Jenkins instances from interfering with each other rather than checking for a local resource on the node.

NOTE:
I cannot use docker instances due to my build environment, so unfortunately that avenue is out of the question for me.

Comment: Jenkins nodes on a developer machine is a crazy approach. According to your second paragraph: `This is because our applications / simulator utilize shared memory resources.`... shared memory resources is the reason of your errors?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no way around this. I agree that this is not a good solution; but my hands are tied. : (